# How to trigger a npm script when Nodemon starts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I'm using [nodemon](https://nodemon.io/) to reload my backend whenever I change some source file on it and I have configured it to trigger a npm script after the start event.

This is my nodemon.json config:

```
{
    "events": {
        "start": "npm run livereload"
    }
}
```

So, what I thought this would do is spawn this `npm run livereload` onde, at the start of nodemon and nevermore. But what happens is that whenever I change something related to the backend, nodemon restart and triggers start event.

What is making me confuse is that there is a `restart` event that is also triggered by nodemon when a change to a backend source files occurs. And I thought that `start` event would trigger once and `restart` event would trigger many times. But this is not what is happening.

So, the queston is, how do I configure nodemon to trigger a npm script just once on the startup?

Comment: See https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/143

Comment: Thanks @brandonscript, but no. The issue that you link has no relation at all to the issue that I'm talking about here. This issue that you mentioned is a way to start a npm script with nodemon managing it. What I'm asking here is a way to trigger any command only on the first 'start' event of a nodemon process.

Comment: Reading over that ticket it looks like it's not possible unless you run nodemon _from_ the npm script. Some of the comments are a little vague, but that was my impression.

Comment: @brandonscript, I thank you again for you time and effort. But looks like you are not understanding the issue here. All that I'm saying, what is bothering me, is that the **start event** is triggered by nodemon every time it restarts. My issue has no relation at all with the one on that ticket.

Comment: I see - so what you're looking for is a way to tie into the nodemon events to determine whether it's a new start or a restart

Comment: @brandonscript, exactly. I have [filed an issue on nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/950), where I question this behaviour. It does not look correct, IMHO, to emit `start` event alongside emitting `restart`. And that is exactly what nodemon is doing.